# Zathura i3 Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, pdf, i3-wm, ubuntu-minimal, zathura

So I have zathura installed on Ubuntu 18.04 with i3-wm. Zathura works all well but every time I close zathura using the Mod+Shift+Q and then open the PDF next time it always starts from the first page, how do I make zathura to open the last previous page that was being read. It used to work well but then I had to install Ubuntu again for some reason

Comment: Apparently Zathura saves the last page in `~/.local/share/zathura/history`. Does that file exist for you? Also have a look at `man zathurarc` and see if you have some setting tweaked.

Comment: Thanks mate, solved this issue. Zathura didn't had enough permissions to access this directory.